# How to save a ref variable for later use?

Tags: c#, reference, ref

So this works..

```
public MyClass(ref Apple apple)
{
    apple = new Apple("Macintosh"); // Works fine
}
```

But is it possible to do something like this?

```
private Apple myApple;

public MyClass(ref Apple apple)
{
    myApple = apple;
}

public void ModifyApple()
{
    myApple = new Apple("Macintosh"); // does not change the input variable like the first example did
}
```

When the ref variable is copied to the member variable `myApple` it appears to lose it's 'ref-ness' and re-assigning it no longer changes the input variable. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really, no. By the time your code is next invoked, the original variable used as the method argument may no longer even exist:

```
void Foo()
{
    MyClass x = Bar();
    x.ModifyApple();
}

MyClass Bar()
{
    Apple apple = new Apple();
    return new MyClass(ref apple);
}
```

Here, `apple` is a *local* variable, in a stack frame which will have been popped by the time we call `ModifyApple`.

Are you sure you need to modify the original caller's *variable* rather than just changing the object itself?

One way to *sort* of fake this would be to use a wrapper type to start with:

```
public class MutableWrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass in a `MutableWrapper<Apple>`, and store that in your class. Then in `ModifyApple` you can write:

```
wrapper.Value = new Apple();
```

This won't change the caller's *variable*, but next time the caller looks at the `Value` property, they'll see your new apple.

To be honest, this sort of thing tends to make for hard-to-maintain code, and even `ref` isn't great for readability. If you can explain the bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to suggest a better overall approach.

Comment: Well, here is what I am trying to get work: http://pastebin.com/v4pNa1um The reason why I cannot pass activeLayer as ref to Undo and Redo is because I don't know what it is at that point. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joey: That doesn't really show the big picture at all - it only shows trying to update some variables. Perhaps you want a stack of undo layers, for example?

Comment: I already have an undo and redo stack in my program. Basically, any undo-able or redo-able action in my program manipulates a tile layer. Before a change is made to the tile layer a new edit is pushed on to the stack and the tile layer is saved before any changes are made. Then if the user ever uses undo or redo it should revert the layer to its saved undo or redo state.

Comment: @Joey: I'm afraid that doesn't help me understand why you feel you need the "ref"-ness here. However, either way it's not available I'm afraid...

Comment: Is there any reason to make Value a property rather than a field?  A field can be used with things like Interlocked methods, whereas a property cannot.

Comment: @supercat: We've already discussed the pros and cons of public fields in other places, and disagreed about it. Even here, I don't think I'd make it a field, for all the reasons we've gone through before. (Most obvious reasons: you may well want to put a breakpoint on the setter, or bind the value to a GUI element.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Those are certainly advantages for using properties instead of fields in situations where the class has some particular meaning, and would I concede that even if one has an exposed field it may be useful to explicitly implement an interface with a property.  I tend to be a fan of using "Plain Old Data" types (all state exposed in public fields) in situations which call for POD semantics, though.  If a class defines its own wrapper class to hold its data, a breakpoint on a setter may be helpful, but a breakpoint on a setter for a widely-used generic wrapper class seems less so.

Comment: @JonSkeet: For example, suppose one uses a `Dictionary<string, MutableWrapper<int>>` to count how many times each string appears in a list, and wants to set a breakpoint each time one of the counts is incremented.  How would one set a breakpoint to distinguish writes to the `MutableWrapper<T>` objects used for that purpose, from writes to other `MutableWrapper<T>` objects used for other purposes?  Is there some practical technique I don't know about?

Comment: @supercat: I would personally just use a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead - why have a wrapper at all there? But in that case, I'd be unlikely to be using two different `MutableWrapper`s at the same time, so I'd *probably* just set the breakpoint when I got to the right area of code, and unset it later. But as I've said before, I don't think we're going to agree on this...

Comment: @JonSkeet: If one puts wrapped objects in the dictionary, each retrieved item will require only one dictionary lookup rather than two.  Also, suppose the goal is to identify the total number of times various strings have arrived from various asynchronous sources.  If the list of strings of interest is predetermined, using Interlocked.Increment on a wrapped integer will eliminate the need for any other locking.  Using a dictionary's indexed setter would necessitate adding locks to any and all dictionary accesses.

Answer (score 9):

`ref`-ness is a property of parameters of functions and arguments you are passing to functions. It's not a property of variables (or even fields) in general.

So indeed, what you are trying there is doomed from the start.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. `myApple` is a field that holds a reference to an `Apple`; the parameter `apple`, however, is actually a reference-to-a-reference-to-an-Apple. When you assign `apple` to `myApple` you *dereference the value of the parameter*. Beyond that, they are separate and distinct.

So no: it is not possible.

What *would* be possible is to have something like:

```
public class AppleWrapper {
    public Apple Value {get;set;}
}
```

Now; if you store an `AppleWrapper`, any number of callers can access *and change* the `.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have `ModifyApple` return the modified Apple instance?

```
public Apple ModifyApple()
{
    myApple = new Apple("Macintosh"); // does not change the input variable like the first example did
    return myApple;
}
```