# How to assign a value in other classes?

Tags: c#, assign

I want to create a aminator class. But it can't modify the field value in other classes.

Here is my simplified animator class:

```
public class PointMover
{
    Point point;
    public void Set(ref Point p)
    {
        point = p;
    }

    public void Move(int dX)
    {
        point.X += dX;  // The point.X is modified here.
    }
}
```

and my main class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PointMover pointMover = new PointMover();
    Point point = new Point(0, 0);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pointMover.Set(ref point);
        pointMover.Move(10); // But point.X is NOT modified here.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my problem. Is there anyone knows how to fix it? I'll be appreciate it.

Comment: Is `Point` a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253377/how-to-save-a-ref-variable-for-later-use

Comment: @DStanley `Point` is a struct.

Comment: This can't be done. You have to wrap `Point` in a class. You *could* use unsafe code, but I'm going to advise against it, I think that would create more problems for you than what it would solve.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I create a class MyPoint to replace the struct Point and it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Point` is a struct (i.e. value type). You pass it by reference, but you then create copy of point instance in constructor of `PointMover` by assigning it to `point` field:

```
public void Set(ref Point p)
{
    point = p; // here you create copy of passed point
}
```

Thus modifications of `point` don't affect `p` (because they represent different instances of structure).

Note: If `Point` would be a reference type (i.e. class) then this assignment would copy a reference, and both variables would have references to same instance in heap.

---

In order to fix this behavior, you need to modify point which was passed by reference without creating copy. E.g.

```
public static void Move(ref Point point, int dX)
{
    point.X += dX; 
}
```

Usage:

```
PointMover.Move(ref point, 20);
```

Or you can simply use [`Point.Offset(int dx, int dy)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awfkydw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you! Both of these two methods are good. But in my situation, I need to pass the Point once and the Mover class automaticly move the point several times to generate the pan animation. So it seems I have to choose the first method that use a class to replace the struct.