# How to keep a reference to another object in current object

Tags: c#, reference, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I know this is possible to have a reference to another object in a method by using `ref` keyword. Created object in the following example inside the method is also available outside of the method.

```
public Method(ref OtherClass input)
{ 
    input = new OtherClass();
}
```

But I need to get one step ahead. I need to hold the reference as a property in my object and change the original object whenever I want in other methods in future.

```
public class CLass1
{
    OtherClass  _input;
    public Bind(ref OtherClass input)
    {
            input = new OtherClass(); // instantiating the object
            _input = input; // keeping a reference of the created object for later usage!
    }
    public void Unbind()
    {
        _input = null;
    }
}
```

When I `Bind` the object the original object initialized with a new object and this is exactly what I want. But after that I run `Unbind()` only the _`input` becomes null and `input` remains intact. I need the `input` becomes null too! How is that possible?

Comment: Sometime global variables are so useful for stress relief..... (just kidding, I don't think that's possible, let's see if someone has the cure)

Comment: It is not possible as such, you will have to have some kind of event system, or use the property from this class everywhere to achieve this.

Comment: Please, look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7253417/3888877

Comment: This is what events are for.  Your class can raise an event anytime `input` is changed and any other class that needs to be aware of changes to `input` can subscribe to the event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a ref variable for later use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253377/how-to-save-a-ref-variable-for-later-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do exactly the thing that you are asking, but you can achieve the functionality if you wrap your OtherClass with WrapperClass

```
public class WrapperClass
{
   public OtherClass Input;
}


public class CLass1
    {
        WrapperClass _wrapper;
        public Bind(ref WrapperClass wrapper)
        {
                wrapper = new WrapperClass();
                wrapper.Input = new OtherClass(); // instantiating the object
                _wrapper = wrapper; // keeping a reference of the created object for later usage!
        }
        public void Unbind()
        {
            _wrapper.Input= null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful. But what is the difference between `_wrapper.Input= null;` and `_wrapper= null;`? First one is global but the second one is local. Why?

Comment: Think about reference like printed page with directions how to go to some address. If you and me have a copy with the same address "A" printed, we both will come to the same place A, but still you look on one page and I look on other one. Now think someone can erase the address from your page and write there other address: "B". So now if you follow directions on your page you will come to address B, while I still come to address A. putting null to the reference is like erase the address from your page, so you have empty page. I still have my page with address A.

Comment: In the solution that I have proposed is reference to object WrapperClass that has the reference to the actual class: OtherClass. Is like even if we have pages, you never erase address from your page, so we always have same address, then when we both go to the same address A, we both find there another page with direction to next address. If somebody eraises this page, then we both come to address A, find this page and see that it is empty (null). I hope this analogy was OK.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, because `ref` is meaningful only as a parameter of a method. You cannot store a reference beyond the scope of a method, because you do not know about the scope of the variable that was passed by reference into your method. For example, think what would happen if you do this:

```
class WithRef {
    // Imagine you can do this
    public ref OtherClass other;
    public WithRef(ref OtherClass other) {
        this.other = other;
    }
}
```

Now let's say you do this:

```
WithRef MakeRef() {
    OtherObject variable;
    return new WithRef(ref variable);
}
void Test() {
    var invalid = MakeRef();
}
```

At this point `invalid` references a local variable inside `MakeRef` method, which is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public abstract class SelfRefType
   <T extends< SelfRefType<T>>  { 
        private OtherType<T>_ref; 
        protected abstract T getThis(); 
        public  void set() {
            _ref.m( getThis() ); }
   }  

    public interface OtherType<E> { 
          void m(E arg); 
    }   

  public  Subtype extends 
        SellfRefType<Subtype>  { 
      protected Subtype getThis() {
      return this; } 
   }
```