# passing an event as an argument

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I use a library<sup>[1]</sup> that defines some stuff I would like to make use of:

```
public delegate void FooHandler(int i);
public delegate void BarHandler(string s);

public class Foo
{
    public event FooHandler Fooh;
}

public class Bar
{
    public event BarHandler Barh;
}
```

I would like to have a short term memory, that I can "attach" to these events:

```
public class ShortTermMemory<T>
{

    public ShortTermMemory(??? arg)
    {
        arg += t => Remeber = t;
    }

    public T Remember { get; private set; }
}
```

and attach them somewhere like

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
var intmemory = new ShortTermMemory<int>(foo.Fooh);
var stringmemory = new ShortTermMemory<string>(bar.Barh);
```

This is impossible because:

- ??? is (somewhat understandably) not a valid type declaration, and
- "The event can only be used on the left hand side of += or -="

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or is this fundamentally impossible in C#? I would like to have compile time guarantees that `ShortTermMemory` is only "fed" by one event source, which is known at compile time to have a single argument of type T.

<sup>[1]: Example implementation for demonstration purposes only</sup>

Comment: The type of ??? is either `FooHandler` or `BarHandler` depending on which event, also as the compiler says you cannot access the event handler outside of the containing class except by += or -=.

Answer (score 1):

With the compile time guarantees you are expecting it isn't possible in C#. There are a few problems there:

1. `event`s are backed by a private delegate field which has a combined invocation list. This is considered an implementation detail, thus the private access.
2. We need to reference the event's delegate field to apply `add` and `remove` (`+=`/`-=`) operators with `Delegate.Combine`/`Remove`.
3. As C# handles delegates as own types, we should have a generic definition of both `FooHandler` and `BarHandler`.
4. You're missing an unsubscription from the event, possibly placed in the destructor of `` ShortTermMemory`1 ``. At this time, the event object may not exist anymore, see [How to save a ref variable for later use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253377/how-to-save-a-ref-variable-for-later-use)

Answer (score -1):

Working solution:

```
public delegate void Handler<T> ( T i );

public class Foo
{
    public event Handler<int> Fooh;

    public void Set(int i) {
        if (Fooh != null) {
            Fooh(i);
        }
    }
}

public class ShortTermMemory<T>
{
    object obj = null;
    string eventName;
    Handler<T> handler;

    public ShortTermMemory (object obj, string eventName) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.handler = new Handler<T>(Set);

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        EventInfo info = type.GetEvent(eventName);

        info.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
    }

    ~ShortTermMemory() {
        if (obj != null) {
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            EventInfo info = type.GetEvent(eventName);

            info.RemoveEventHandler(obj, handler);
        }
    }

    public T Remember { get; set; }

    public void Set(T t) {
        Remember = t;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
var intmemory1 = new ShortTermMemory<int>(foo, "Fooh");
var intmemory2 = new ShortTermMemory<int>(foo, "Fooh");

foo.Set(10);
```

Comment: I don't plan on maintaining a fork of the Library that contains Foo at this point though